# Import numbers as strings though read_excel

Tags: r

I'm using  `read_excel`  to import some poorly formatted data, that contains numbers which are supposed to be understood as characters:

```
          measurement    value
1                 1.1    2
2                 1.2    0
3                 1.3    0
4                 1.4    0
5                 1.5    3
6                 1.6    0
7                 1.7    0
8                 1.8    1
9                 1.9    0
10               1.10    0
11               1.11    0
12               1.12    0
```

Here, the values in the "measurement" column aren't numeric values, but strings that denote specific types of measurements (e.g. measurement 1.2 is simply the second measurement on a list). The numbers in the "value" column are numeric.

Importing these data returns the following:

- 1.10 (= measurement 10) is interpreted as 1.1
- due to the floating point problem, decimals are introduced

```
          measurement    value
1  1.1000000000000001    2
2                 1.2    0
3                 1.3    0
4                 1.4    0
5                 1.5    3
6                 1.6    0
7                 1.7    0
8                 1.8    1
9                 1.9    0
10 1.1000000000000001    0
11 1.1100000000000001    0
12 1.1200000000000001    0
```

How can I get R to see the measurement values as strings and not as numbers, so that no alterations occur?

Edit: Is it also possible to specify the data type of only one column? My Excel actually contains many columns and it's a bit impractical to have to specify the data type of all of them, even though most of them are interpreted correctly.

Comment: Already tried `openxlsx::read.xlsx`?

Answer (score 2):

###### Read the Excel file with explicit data types

```
data <- read_excel(file_path, col_types = c("text", "numeric"))
```

Comment: Thank you, but while this imports the measurement numbers as characters, the floating point problem doesn't get resolved: it's still "1.10000000001".